# can anyone identify these bags of Lego? lots of dark and light grey, dark red

Tags: set-identification

Found these Lego bags but don't the set they belong to.
What set are they part of?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like two sets.

Top right bag seems to be a Death Star UCS.

Based on

- at least 5 White Technic, Plate 2 x 4 with 3 Holes
- Light Bluish Gray Brick 2 x 2 Corner
- Dark Bluish Gray Technic Reel 3 x 2

Those pieces together seem to only belong to [10188-1 Death Star - UCS](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10188-1)

[image: 10188-1]

The top left bag seems to have pieces from this, too:

- Dark Bluish Gray Dish 2 x 2 Inverted (Radar)
- Dark Bluish Gray Plate 2 x 2 Corner
- Light Bluish Gray Minifigure, Weapon Lightsaber Hilt Straight
- Light Bluish Gray Technic, Pin Connector Round 2L with Slot (Pin Joiner Round)

The middle left bag seems to have pieces from this, too:

- Light Bluish Gray Bar 6L with Stop Ring
- Dark Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Handle on Side - Free Ends
- Tan Plate, Round 2 x 2 with Rounded Bottom (Boat Stud)
- Light Bluish Gray Hinge Plate 1 x 2 Locking with 2 Fingers on Side and 9 Teeth
- Red Plate, Round 2 x 2 with Axle Hole

The bottom right bag seems to also have pieces from this set.

The bottom left bag, however seems to be from [76104-1 The Hulkbuster Smash-Up](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=76104-1)

- Dark Bluish Gray Tile, Modified 2 x 2 Inverted
- Pearl Gold Slope, Curved 2 x 2 x 2/3 with Two Studs and Curved Sides
- Dark Bluish Gray Technic, Brick Modified 2 x 2 with Ball Socket and Axle Hole - Straight Forks with Round Ends and Open Sides

These 3 together only occur in 2 sets, and only 1 of them has all that Dark Red.

[image: 76104-1]