# What sets do these go to? Large grey plates and Technic and giant grey dish

Tags: set-identification

Please, what sets do these go to?
Can anyone identify these parts?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the bottom right bag, it's [also](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17460/can-anyone-identify-these-bags-of-lego-lots-of-dark-and-light-grey-dark-red) the Death Star

Based on

- Dark Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 8 x 8 with Grille and Hole in Center
- Light Bluish Gray Cone 3 x 3 x 2

These two only appear together in

[10188-1 Death Star - UCS](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10188-1)

[image: 10188-1]