# Identify these bags: mostly grey and black

Tags: set-identification

No luck identifying what set these belong to.
Can anyone help?

[image: 5 bags]

Comment: The picture looks identical to <https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/what-sets-do-these-go-to-large-grey-plates-and-technic-and-giant-grey-dish>

Answer (score 2):

Based on a [search for sets containing 12x6 wings in light gray and 4x4 round plates in black](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=30355&itemSeq1=2&colorID1=86&itemNo2=60474&itemSeq2=4&colorID2=11&itemNo3=&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=&in=S), this can be identified as part of UCS Death Star, either [set 10188-1 from 2008](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10188-1) or [set 75159-1 from 2016](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10188-1):

[image: UCS Death Star]

The inventory for the set fits most of the bags in your photograph - parts like the 8x8 black tile, or the 10x10 light gray radar dish, 8x8 grille plate, or the 3x1 technic beam can be seen in both.

---

The bag on the lower left, however, is from a different set. Based on the [2x2 corner plates in tan](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2420), [1x4 inverted curved slope in light grey](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=13547) and [1x6 plate in dark tan](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=3666), a [search](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=2420&itemSeq1=2&colorID1=2&itemNo2=3666&itemSeq2=4&colorID2=69&itemNo3=13547&itemSeq3=2&colorID3=86&in=S) points to two sets: either [75151-1 Clone Turbo Tank](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75151-1) or [75292 The Razor Crest](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75292-1).