# I picked up these bags of Lego - mostly greys and black

Tags: set-identification

I picked up these bags of legos at a garage sale but don't know what the set is they belong to.
Can you help me with identifying what set they belong to?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The top right bag has [a rare windscreen](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30366pb03&in=S) and [a half-cylinder](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6259&colorID=85&in=A). In those colors, they [still](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/what-sets-do-these-go-to-large-grey-plates-and-technic-and-giant-grey-dish) only show up in [10188-1 Death Star - UCS](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10188-1).

Comment: Set 10188 has a lot more parts than are in this bag.

Comment: Yup. Obviously, bags 1, 3, 4, 5, and 6 aren't in the photo.

Comment: So your saying that the 6 bags are shown as one bag 7 in the instructions?